# Which SAQs should I be filling as part of PCI DSS self assessment as web developer?

Tags: php, pci-compliance, pci-dss

Which requirements I am oblige to fulfil as self assessment part , as web-developer for eCommerce application. I have lots of [SAQ,s](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/documents.php?category=saqs) (self-assessment-questionnaires) as part of PCI DSS.

What should be scope of concern throughout the development life-cycle.

- Development
- Testing
- Deployment
- Any other aspect you might think ?

Is there any open source tool to support this process (assessment and tracking) etc ?

Comment: The correct SAQ depends on what you are actually doing with card details, which we don't know.  [Understanding_SAQs_PCI_DSS_v3.pdf](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/Understanding_SAQs_PCI_DSS_v3.pdf)

Comment: Actually that is the puzzle , I am currently not storing the card holder data/security tokens in my application.

Comment: PCI applies if you *store, **process or transmit*** details

Comment: @AlexK. thanks I got the list https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/Understanding_SAQs_PCI_DSS_v3.pdf

Comment: I think only transmit for processing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only an QSA can give you an official answer but I can give you some ideas.

How is the web app being used? This will help determine your scope:

- Is it only for your own use? The best scenario is to use an iFrame or full page direct from a PCI compliant provider (generally the payment gateway), this could be SAQ A. If you need to do a direct post (i.e. the credit card details never touch your server) then you may be able to use SAQ A-EP. If the credit card number touches your server then it's SAQ D. Aim for SAQ A it'll save you a big headache.
- Do you provide it for clients to use in their own systems where they have control over the code or servers? Take a look at PA-DSS.
- Do you offer it as a service to clients where they have no control of the system? Then you'd need SAQ D service provider.

Take a look at requirement 6 to get an idea of what is need for the SDLC.

Tools-wise there's the [PCI scoping toolkit](https://www.isaca.org/Groups/Professional-English/pci-compliance/GroupDocuments/OpenPCIScopingToolkit.pdf), i'm not sure that's what you're asking for though.

Comment: Thanks that is much elaborated